# Why is my local storage item removed after a short period automatically?

Tags: reactjs, popup, local-storage

I have a custom popup modal for user authentication in react.js and it redirects to the main page after successful authentication.

Meanwhile, it should save a local storage item named `accessToken` in [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

But what I've noticed is that the `accessToken` is saved in local storage sometimes, but sometimes the `accessToken` is removed automatically even it is saved beforehand.

[image]

In other words, it doesn't work every time, just works sometimes.

Here's my login popup.

```
import React, {
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    useState
} from 'react';
import { number } from "yup";

const createPopup = ({
    url,
    title,
    height,
    width,
}) => {
    const left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - width) / 2;
    const top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - height) / 2.5;

    return window.open(
        url,
        title,
        `width=${width}, height=${height}, left=${left}, top=${top}`,
    );
};

const LoginPopup = ({
    title = '',
    width = 500,
    height = 500,
    url,
    children,
    onCode,
    onClose,
}) => {
    const [externalWindow, setExternalWindow] = useState(Window | null);
    const intervalRef = useRef(number);

    const clearTimer = () => {
        window.clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    };

    const onContainerClick = () => {
        setExternalWindow(createPopup({
            url, title, width, height,
        }));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (externalWindow) {
            intervalRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
                try {
                    const currentUrl = externalWindow.location.href;
                    const params = new URL(currentUrl).searchParams;
                    const code = params.get('code');

                    if (!code) {
                        return;
                    }

                    onCode(code, params);
                    clearTimer();
                    externalWindow.close();
                } catch (error) {
                    // eslint-ignore-line
                } finally {
                    if (!externalWindow || externalWindow.closed) {
                            onClose();
                            clearTimer();
                    }
                }
            }, 200);
        }

        return () => {
            if (externalWindow) externalWindow.close();
            if (onClose) onClose();
        };
    }, [externalWindow]);

    return (
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        <div onClick={() => onContainerClick()}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginPopup;
```

`onCode` is from [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```
const setSession = (key, value) => {
  if (key && value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
};

...
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const login = async (accessToken, params) => {
    setSession('accessToken', accessToken);

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${domain}/api/v1/account`);
      const user = response?.data;

      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
          user
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialise = async () => {
    ...
    };
    initialise();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        ...
        login,
        logout
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const AuthContext;
```

Not sure why it is removed immediately after the popup is closed even it is saved in the local storage but a very short period.

I am pretty sure the back-end has the correct redirection url so it should work correctly.

Comment: Where is the code which sets/removes the localStorage key?

Comment: @ChrisB. Just updated `setSession` function. But I was not able to find any delete local storage process. I tried console log in the user authentication process one by one step by step.

Comment: @ChrisB. Could you look at this issue please?